# calling many javascript from a view in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I will like to call two Javascript.js fonction from my view.  I cannot find the proper way to do it.

My view has a text box to be able to change the quantity number of the item.
I have a link to click if we want to refresh the quantity.   It will recalculate the price multiply to the quantity of the item.

I have another link to click if we want to remove the item from the cart.

I isolate the two scripts under Scripts/Js
 - RefreshQuantity.js
 - RemoveFromCart.js

In my View, how should be the call the these two javascripts ?

I tried this but only the RefreshQuantity script is working.

Note:  The javascripts are working fine if I leave them in the view.  But I know the proper way
       of doing scripts is to isolate them under a folder Scripts/Js.

Index.cshtml

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="~/Scripts/Js/RemoveFromCart.js"></script>

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Js/RefreshQuantity.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any input to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bundles feature of MVC and then add the necessary declaration to the bottom of your layout view. Don't pull separate scripts directly into your views - this will be a maintenance nightmare.

[ASP.Net MVC 4 Bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948862/asp-net-mvc-4-bundles)